# sum values in a loop if another value is false

Tags: php, loops

I am new to php and I messed it up my code little bit. I would appreciate any help.

```
$sqltest="SELECT MaId,Amount FROM table1";
$stmttest = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sqltest);
if( $stmttest === false) {
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
}
while($test = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmttest, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){ //fetch array
$combined[] = array($test['MaId']=>$test['Amount']); //pass the first column values as array keys
}
$loop=0;
foreach ($combined as $key => $value) {
    foreach ($value as $msid => $msamount) {
       while($msid!==25) {
          $loop += $msamount;
       }
    }
 }
```

I am trying to sum the all the amounts where the id is not equal to 25, but
I'm getting stuck in an infinite loop. Can you explain what's going wrong?

Comment: Why not `SELECT SUM(Amount) FROM table1 WHERE MaId <> 25`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `while` you have should be an `if`

```
if($msid!==25) {
   $loop += $msamount;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Change:

```
while($msid!==25) {
```

to:

```
if ($msid!==25) {
```

And I have to agree with [Mark Baker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/324584/mark-baker) ([commented above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18969106/php-sum-values-in-a-loop-if-another-value-is-false/18969125#comment28017608_18969106)), if you can do this in the database, you should:

```
$sqltest = 'SELECT SUM(Amount) AS Amount FROM table1 WHERE MaId <> 25';
$stmttest = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sqltest);

if ($stmttest === false) {
    die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

$amount = 0;

if ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmttest, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $amount = $row['Amount'];
}
```